# Error loading Dropbox API script into chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dropbox-api

I'm trying to use the dropbox api in the chrome extension but the console says

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js' because it violates
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   chrome-extension-resource:"

How do I fix this?

I put 
    "permissions": [
    "https://www.dropbox.com"
    ]

but it's still not working

Comment: Try including `https://www.dropbox.com` in your permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to load scripts from external domains, your extension must

1. Include the domain of external script in permissions
2. It must be a https resource

I see that you are loading `https:` already So just adding the `https://www.dropbox.com` to your permissions should solve this issue.

Permissions should look like:

> "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.dropbox.com;
>   object-src 'self'"

Read this from [Content Security Policy Documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#relaxing)

> If you have a need for some external JavaScript or object resources,
>   you can relax the policy to a limited extent by whitelisting secure
>   origins from which scripts should be accepted. We want to ensure that
>   executable resources loaded with an extension's elevated permissions
>   are exactly the resources you expect, and haven't been replaced by an
>   active network attacker

Comment: I put   "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "downloads",
    "https://www.dropbox.com/"
  ] but it's still not working

Comment: Your permissions must include the protocol in domain so please see my edited answer

Comment: sorry about that, I actually did put it in but it changed when it got highlighted. What do I have to put in for csp?

Comment: Try this "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' `https://www.dropbox.com` object-src 'self'"

Answer (score 0):

I think, its good to use wildcard in persmissions like:

```
"permissions": "https://*.dropbox.com/*"
```

as well as include dropbox.js in scripts listing:

```
"background": {
"persistent": true,
  "scripts": [
    "js/dropbox.js",
    "js/background.js"
  ]
},
```

All in your **manifest.json** file.